# Is there any javascript function to debug trace the scripts

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to backtrack from where the function is called in `ExtJS`.

Just like in PHP we have `debug_trace()` which shows the whole chain of methods .

is there something like that available in `extjs` or `javascript`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set a breakpoint in your browser's dev tools of choice and bring up the call stack.

Search "call stack" in the following articles:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Answer (score 0):

if you are using chrome, i know there is a console.trace() which you can add in your code while debugging to bring you the trace, i havent used it on any other to know if it exists on otheres

you can also use the debugger keyword to add breakpoints or you can use the debugger function in your dev console